# How to concat what's being printed in each row to a csv?

Tags: python, csv

I'm transforming an adjacency matrix to an edge list, with this script:

```
tc1 = open("TC1.csv")
to_write = open("t1_list.csv", "a+")

def buildList():
    # tc1 = open("TC1.csv")
    columns = tc1.readline().strip().split(',')[1:]
    for i, line in enumerate(tc1):
        tokens = line.strip().split(',')
        row = tokens[0]
        for column, cell in zip(columns[i:],tokens[i+1:]):
            print '{},{},{}'.format(row,column,cell)
            to_write.write(str('{},{},{}'.format(row,column,cell)))

buildList()
```

When printing on the console, it correctly displays an edge list, something like this:

```
209,209,0
209,210,0
209,211,0
209,212,0
209,213,0
209,214,0
210,210,0
210,211,0
210,212,0
210,213,0
210,214,0
211,211,0
211,212,0
211,213,0
211,214,0
212,212,0
212,213,0
212,214,0
213,213,0
```

However, when I write into the csv, the csv looks like this:

1,1,01,2,01,3,01,4,01,5,01,6,01,7,01,8,01,9,01,10,01,11,01,12,01,13,01,14,01,15,01,16,01,17,01,18,01,19,01,20,01,21,01,22,01,23,01,24,01,25,01,26,01,27,01,28,01,29,01,30,01,31,01,32,01,33,01,34,01,35,01,36,01,37,01,38,01,39,01,40,01,41,01,42,01,43,01,44,01,45,01,46,01,47,01,48,01,49,01,50,01,51,01,52,01,53,01,54,01,55,01,56,01,57,01,58,01,59,01,60,01,61,01,62,01,63,01,64,01,65,01,66,01,67,01,68,01,69,01,70,01,71,01,72,01,73,01,74,01,75,01,76,01,77,01,78,01,79,01,80,01,81,01,82,01,83,01,84,01,85,01,86,01,87,01,88,01,89,01,90,01,91,01,92,01,93,01,94,01,95,01,96,01,97,01,98,01,99,01,100,01,101,01,102,01,103,01,104,01,105,01,106,01,107,01,108,01,109,01,110,01,111,01,112,01,113,01,114,01,115,01,116,01,117,01,118,01,119,01,120,11,121,01,122,01,123,01,124,01,125,01,126,01,127,01,128,01,129,01,130,01,131,01,132,01,133,01,134,01,135,01,136,01,137,01,138,01,139,01,140,01,141,01,142,01,143,01,144,01,145,01,146,01,147,01,148,01,149,01,150,01,151,01,152,01,153,01,154,01,155,01,156,01,157,01,158,01,159,01,160,01,161,01,162,01,163,01,164,01,165,01,166,01,167,01,168,01,169,01,170,01,171,01,172,01,173,01,174,01,175,01,176,01,177,01,178,01,179,01,180,01,181,01,182,01,183,01,184,01,

Comment: if you work on csv files, use the stdlib's csv module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a linebreak character at the end:

```
to_write.write(str('{},{},{}\n'.format(row,column,cell)))
```